# Import and use nano-memoize in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, memoization

I am trying to use Nano-memoize in my React based web application which also uses Typescript and Webpack.

I have followed the following steps:

- `npm install nano-memoize`
- added `import * as nanomemoize from 'nano-memoize'` to my source file.
- memoized a function like `const memoizedFunc = nanomemoize(myFunc)`

`myFunc` takes two arguments - a string and an string[].

However, I don't see the memoization happening because the debug statements in `myFunc` are getting printed for same arguments.
How should this be done the right way?

Comment: I guess the parameters passed to the memoizedFunc changed. Note that `{hi:1}!=={hi:1}` and `x=>x!==x=>x`. So if you call memoizedFunc like `memoizedFunc({name,id})` then you may as well not use it. If you are using redux then you should take a look at [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) or look at useMemo and useCallback hooks.

Comment: "However, I don't see the memoization happening." what makes you say that? how are you checking if memoization "happened"?

Comment: @Peter the debug statements in "myFunc" are getting printed for same arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nano-memoize doesn't do deep equals comparison of arguments. The string[] arguments passed in to `myFunct` is different object each time and consequently memoization doesn't work.

To fix this I am forced to use lodast.isquals as an option in nano-memoize

```
const memoizedFunc = nanomemoize(myFunc, {
    // deep equals required since one of the parameter is a string array
    equals : (x, y) => isequal(x, y),
});
```